# Remove dict from list of matching values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dict,

```
list dict =  [
         {'children': [], 'folder': 'test2', 'parent': 'None'},
         {'children': [{'children': [], 'folder': 'arun2', 'parent': 'arun2'}],
          'folder': 'arun2',
          'parent': 'None'},
         {'children': [], 'folder': 'important', 'parent': 'None'},
         {'children': [], 'folder': 'arun', 'parent': 'None'},
         {'children': [], 'folder': 'hoi', 'parent': 'None'},
         {'children': [], 'folder': 'drafts', 'parent': 'None'},
         {'children': [], 'folder': 'Trash', 'parent': 'None'},
         {'children': [], 'folder': 'sent', 'parent': 'None'},
         {'children': [], 'folder': 'spam', 'parent': 'None'},
         {'children': [], 'folder': 'reference', 'parent': 'None'},
         {'children': [], 'folder': 'test3', 'parent': 'None'},
         {'children': [], 'folder': 'test1', 'parent': 'None'},
         {'children': [], 'folder': 'INBOX', 'parent': 'None'} 
        ]
```

Now i want to remove dict from `list_dict` that has all the values in the  `remove_key_list`

```
remove_key_list = ['INBOX','sent','Trash']
```

For example i want remove `{'children': [], 'folder': 'INBOX', 'parent': 'None'}` from `list dict` and return the `list dict`

I'm new to python how to use `del` , `lamda` functions here.

Comment: so you want to *remove `dict` from `list_dict` that has **any** keys from the remove_key_list*, right? not **all**..

Comment: Also, do you want this to be recursive? You seem to have nested dicts as well..

Comment: none of your dicts have keys mentioned in `remove_key_list`, you want to remove dicts with `values` mabe?

Comment: Are the checks case-sensitive? Your question is so vague that it is un-answerrable as it stands

Comment: yes. removing the dict if `dict['folder'] == 'INBOX'` and any other key from `remove_key_list`

Comment: Do you mean key or value, because there is no key in `list_dict` matching any of the `remove_key_list` but value does.

Comment: Sorry. Its values not key. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you only want to remove the dicts that equals the `folder` to one of your `remove_key_list` this should do the job.

```
list_dict =  [
         {'children': [], 'folder': 'test2', 'parent': 'None'},
         {'children': [{'children': [], 'folder': 'arun2', 'parent': 'arun2'}],
          'folder': 'arun2',
          'parent': 'None'},
         {'children': [], 'folder': 'important', 'parent': 'None'},
         {'children': [], 'folder': 'arun', 'parent': 'None'},
         {'children': [], 'folder': 'hoi', 'parent': 'None'},
         {'children': [], 'folder': 'drafts', 'parent': 'None'},
         {'children': [], 'folder': 'Trash', 'parent': 'None'},
         {'children': [], 'folder': 'sent', 'parent': 'None'},
         {'children': [], 'folder': 'spam', 'parent': 'None'},
         {'children': [], 'folder': 'reference', 'parent': 'None'},
         {'children': [], 'folder': 'test3', 'parent': 'None'},
         {'children': [], 'folder': 'test1', 'parent': 'None'},
         {'children': [], 'folder': 'INBOX', 'parent': 'None'} 
        ]

filter_list = ['INBOX', 'sent', 'Trash']

filtered_list = [d for d in list_dict if d['folder'] not in filter_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for k,i in enumerate(list(list_dict)):
    if i['folder'] in remove_folder_list:
        del list_dict[list_dict.index(i)]

print(list_dict)
```